# why does "echo [0123456789]" return "1"?

Tags: bash

Can you help me understand why this happens:

```
$ echo [023456789]
[023456789]

$ echo [0123456789]
1
```

With your feedback, I'm hoping I can figure out how to write a bash script that can take an argument with the value of [0123456789] and assign that literal string to a variable.

Answer (score 5):

You have a file named '1' in your current directory.

```
echo [0123456789]
```

is a wildcard command that tells bash to display the names of any files in the current directory whose names are comprised of a single digit.  If no such files exist, echo will display the wildcard spec itself.

Notice:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/new-directory
$ cd /tmp/new-directory
$ echo [0123456789]
[0123456789]

$ touch 1 2 4 8
$ echo [0123456789]
1 2 4 8
```

If you want to display that string literally, instead of displaying the filenames that it matches, enclose the string in quotes:

```
$ echo "[0123456789]"
[0123456789]
```

Comment: Yes--you nailed it! And I thought I was "good" at bash and googling.... :( Thank you!!!